# Copy Local = True vs. Add Deployable Dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Looking to make my MVC application be bin-deployable, I am confused by the difference between two ways of packaging up libraries along with my application.

1. Add Deployable Dependencies

You can right-click on your project, select "Add Deployable Dependencies", you will be presented with:

[Add Deployable Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKr7t.png)

This will create a folder in your solution called "_bin_deployableAssemblies" which contains the set of dll's that corresponded to your selection.

1. Set Copy Local to "True"

I can find the same dll's listed in the "References" folder in the Solution Explorer.  You can right click and select properties to set "Copy Local" to "True".

[Copy Local = True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4tUr.png)

What is the basic difference between these two methods?  They seem to perform the same function.  Which is better to use and could this be causing dll version conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'Add Deployable Dependencies' will automatically do what Copy Local = true does, but to every required dll, so the process of setting them up manually is automated.

I presume you are using VS 2010? because according to this blog post: http://samirvaidya.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/deployable-dependencies-option-missing.html
2012 doesn't have this property anymore, all required dlls are bin deployed.

I've always used 'Add Deployable Dependencies' and had no problems with dll version conflicts, I find it to be safe.

Comment: Thanks. So basically Copy Local = true in VS2010 will not ensure that any dependant dll's will also be copied over.